# RecordLinkage: change unit of analysis, how to export all linked matches within deduplicated dataset into one row of new dataframe?

Tags: r, record-linkage

I am attempting to change the unit of analysis of a dataset from incidents reported, to individuals who reported incidents. As the same individual has reported more than once, I have used the compare.dedup function from R's RecordLinkage package to identify match pairs - i.e. pairs of incidents reported by the same person. However, I am struggling to export all of the pairs into one dataset for further analysis.

Here's some code for dummy data:

```r
incidents <- structure(
  list(
    date = as.Date(c("01-02-2014", "02-02-2014", "02-02-2014", "03-02-2014", "04-02-2014","05-02-2014"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    first_name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), 
                         .Label = c("Dave", "Joe", "David", "Joseph", "Jo","Dave"),
                         class = "factor"),
    last_name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L),
                      .Label = c("Evans", "Miles", "Evans", "Myles",
                                 "Doe","Evans"), 
                      class = "factor"),
    sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
                  .Label = c("Male", "Female"), class = "factor"),
    dob = as.Date(c("14-02-1988", "01-05-1987", "14-02-1988", "01-05-1987", "04-02-1999","14-02-1988"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")),
  .Names = c("Date","Name","Surname","Sex","DOB"),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)
)
```

When printed "incidents" looks like this:

```r
        Date   Name Surname    Sex        DOB
1 2014-02-01   Dave   Evans   Male 1988-02-14
2 2014-02-02    Joe   Miles   Male 1987-05-01
3 2014-02-02  David   Evans   Male 1988-02-14
4 2014-02-03 Joseph   Myles   Male 1987-05-01
5 2014-02-04     Jo     Doe Female 1999-02-04
6 2014-02-05   Dave   Evans   Male 1988-02-14
```

I have managed to print pairs in a single row but what I am after is to cluster all into a single row (see below).

I have run the following code to identify and extract the matched pairs:

```r
# Generating the pairs

pairs = compare.dedup(incidents,
                      identity = NA, 
                      blockfld = FALSE,
                      phonetic = c(2), #runs phonetic comparison
                      phonfun = pho_h,
                      strcmp = c(3,4,5), #runs a string comparison
                      strcmpfun = levenshteinSim, #use levenshtein distance
                      exclude = c(1))

# Generating the weights
weightedpairs = emWeights(pairs, cutoff = 0.7)

#Classify the pairs
emresult = emClassify(weightedpairs)
```

I can get linked pairs in single row:

```r
links=getPairs(emresult,show="links", single.rows=TRUE)

links

    id1     Date.1 Name.1 Surname.1 Sex.1      DOB.1 id2     Date.2 Name.2 Surname.2 Sex.2      DOB.2    Weight
1.1   1 2014-02-01   Dave     Evans  Male 1988-02-14   6 2014-02-05   Dave     Evans  Male 1988-02-14 20.876240
1     1 2014-02-01   Dave     Evans  Male 1988-02-14   3 2014-02-02  David     Evans  Male 1988-02-14 10.208543
3     3 2014-02-02  David     Evans  Male 1988-02-14   6 2014-02-05   Dave     Evans  Male 1988-02-14 10.208543
2     2 2014-02-02    Joe     Miles  Male 1987-05-01   4 2014-02-03 Joseph     Myles  Male 1987-05-01  9.886615
```

However, what I would like to achieve is to merge all matches so I end up with one row per individual, by date of reporting. Something more or less like this:

```r
        Date   Name Surname    Sex        DOB    Date2       Name2    Surname2    Sex2    DOB2    Date3    Name3    Surname3    Sex3    DOB3
1 2014-02-01   Dave   Evans   Male 1988-02-14    2014-02-02  David    Evans Male    1988-02-14    2014-02-05   Dave   Evans   Male 1988-02-14
2 2014-02-02    Joe   Miles   Male 1987-05-01    2014-02-03  Joseph   Myles Male    1987-05-01
3 2014-02-04     Jo     Doe Female 1999-02-04    NA          NA       NA
```

I wonder if anyone has suggestions of how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But how would you go about the case that e.g. `1` matches `2` and `2` matches `3`but `3`doesn't match `1`? Would you have `2` in two rows then or put `3` and `1` into one row?

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen in my case I want to link 1, 2 and 3 where that occurs. I have found a solution to this and will post a complete answer as soon as I have a chance but it basically involved creating an index common to each pair that matched as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56739733/how-to-create-a-column-index-based-on-either-of-two-conditions-being-met-to-ena In the scenario you describe, each of the cases 1, 2 and 3 would share the same unique index / identifier. This would then enable a merge.